# Why abs(intmin) ~= -intmin in matlab

Tags: matlab, integer-overflow

```
EDU>> intmin 
    ans =

    -2147483648

EDU>> abs(intmin)

     ans =

     2147483647
```

How is this possible? There must be some sort of overflow or the definitions of these functions are mingling in strange ways.

Comment: Check [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) and ranges for 32-bit numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For 2's complement signed integers of 32 bits, `intmin` is `0x80000000`, or indeed `-2147483648`. However, `intmax` is `0x7FFFFFFF`, which is only `2147483647`. This means that the negation of `intmin` would be `2147483648`, which can't be represented in 32-bit signed integers.

MATLAB actually does something odd. Under the normal rules of 2's complement, `0 - 0x80000000` should give `0x80000000` again. However, according to MATLAB, `0 - 0x80000000 = 0x7FFFFFFF`. This should explain why `abs(intmin) = intmax` holds for MATLAB (but not necessarily in other languages).

This oddity has an interesting side-effect, however: you can assume that `abs` never returns a negative number.

Comment: MATLAB uses saturation rather than the "wrap around" behavior you see in languages such as C. Besides I think that overflow of signed integers in C is *undefined behavior*

Answer (score 5):

In order to encode zero, there must be asymmetry among positive/negative two's complement integers.

Indeed, you are seeing integer overflow (saturation).

Answer (score 2):

For each [integer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html#f2-98095) data type, there is a largest and smallest number that you can represent with that type:

[image: integer_type_range]

When the result of an expression involving integers exceeds the maximum (or minimum) value of the data type, MATLAB maps the values that are outside the limit to the nearest endpoint. This [saturation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic) behavior explains what you are seeing rather than a weird case of [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) in binary representation (which "wraps around" in 2's complement).

Example:

```
>> x = int8(100)
x =
  100
>> x + x
ans =
  127
```